# scilab is not showing any graphical plot

Tags: scilab

I am new to scilab. I am trying to do a simple 2d plot but unfortunately it is not plotting anything.

When I open scilab and run plot, it shows a window named 'graphic window number 0' but shows no plot.

when I try to run scilab-bin, it shows following error:
scilab-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libjava.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I used sudo apt install scilab.

Should I install more packages?

Comment: Please give the output (on the terminal) when Scilab is launched and when the plot2d command is issued.

Comment: with scilab-cli:
Undefined variable: plot
with scilab-adv-cli:
a graphic window appears and no plot. The error is too long, cant paste here.

Comment: Include the error message (at least the first 10 lines) in your  question above, between two ~~~~ lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used sudo apt install scilab.

If you installed Scilab from (Ubuntu or derivatives) repository it will probably not work. The package is somehow broken (since I can think).

Quick and dirty: Go to [scilab.org](https://www.scilab.org/download/scilab-6.1.1), download the tar.gz, decompress it and run the script called "`scilab`" in the bin-directory.

Answer (score 0):

For me the graphical plot utility doesn't work, either I install Scilab from Flathub or decompress the tar.gz file they have on the official [scilab.org](https://www.scilab.org) site (and follow the instructions).

The only thing I've found is that you can export the graph in pdf even if you can't see it in the graphical window and then, open the exported file with the pdf viewer as usual. This is enough for my necessities atm.

Hope somebody finds this comment useful.

Answer (score 0):

`LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./bin/scilab`

credits: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333764/scilab-graphic-window-appear-but-it-is-blank-there-is-no-plot-ubuntu-20-04-lts

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djogl.disable.openglcore=false"  scilab &

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).